# no download and install progress, no error message (no text at all!) for sudo gem install merb

Tags: rubygems

I'm using ruby 4.2, rubygems 1.3.5-1ubuntu2 and Ubuntu Lucid Lynx. I installed ruby and rubygems with Synaptic.

Since "The gem command will output its progress while it sucks down and installs all the necessary gems for a full Merb install. " is written at http://wiki.merbivore.com/howto/installation/gems, when I type `sudo gem update --system`, I get: `"ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)

        gem update --system is disabled on Debian. RubyGems can be updated using the official Debian repositories by aptitude or apt-get."` and rubygems has list, build and help commands, I'm wondering if in Ubuntu rubygems is used only for something other than downloading.

If it isn't, why isn't rubygems showing any text for `sudo gem install merb`?

Comment: I don't know gem, but most programs have a verbose option (--verbose or something).  Check the man file for a verbose option, add that, and see if it still gives no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install ruby1.8-dev from apt-get and add rubygems bin dir to sudo path. I think that's what made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Going on the following line

> RubyGems can be updated using the
>   official Debian repositories by
>   aptitude or apt-get.

Open your shell and type the following

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems
```

Also have a look here

http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page14

- This is probably not what your after but thought i would try and get an idea of what's going on

Comment: While trying to install merb, I installed some libraries for ruby, and for merb, then ruby and rubygems from source, then some -dev things from Synaptic, but I think what made it work was isntalling ruby1.8-dev from apt-get and adding rubygems bin dir to sudo path!